# Unique filter in datadog event monitor

Tags: logging, alert, monitoring, datadog

I am looking for a unique filter in the Datadog event monitor. something like below.

[image]

Scenario:

I have multiple microservices running in Kubernetes. Each of the services will produce a  log message in the format `foreground-process thread-<ID> is in waiting for state`. For each `thread-<ID>` multiple log messages would be produced. I am using the pipeline feature with grok parser to fetch `threadType` i.e `foreground-process` and `thread-<ID>` .i.e is `thread-11`. I need to create a monitor and alert when more than 5 unique threads are blocked per service. I can achieve this by creating a separate monitor for each service but then I need to create around 120 monitors. So I am looking to see if there is  `unique` filter in datadog or any other mechanism to achieve this?

Sample logs:

```
foreground-process thread-2 is in waiting for state
foreground-process thread-11 is in waiting for state
foreground-process thread-2 is in waiting for state
foreground-process thread-9 is in waiting for state
foreground-process thread-2 is in waiting for state
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count the unique number of things, change that `*` in the yellow `Count` box to the facet you want to count unique values for.

[image: count unique in monitor]